# Percorrer array XML em PHP

Tags: php, array, xml

Olá.
Tenho esse caminho que é uma posição de um *array* de uma resposta XML, e estou pegando o `IDcli`.

Não consigo fazer um `foreach` que percorra esse *array* e mostrar o `IDcli`.

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($obj);

$xml->sis->cont->Clis->Cli[0]->IDcli;
```

Eu tentei apenas o `for`, mas só conta até *9*:

```php
for ( $j = 0; $j < count( $xml->sis->cont->Clis->Cli[$j]->IDcli ); $j++ ) {
  echo "<br>".$xml->sis->cont->Clis->Cli[$j]->IDcli;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `foreach ($xml->sis->cont->Clis->Cli as $id) { echo $id->IDcli }`?

Comment: Coloquei em baixo como fiz, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz assim, e deu certo.

```php
$tuas_tags = $xml->sis->cont->Clis->Cli[0]->IDcli;

foreach ( $tuas_tags as $tua_tag )
{
    echo "<br>".$tua_tag->IDcli;

}
```

Obrigado quem tentou.

Comment: Mas isso não pega somente o `IDcli` do primeiro índice do array?

Comment: Verdade, mas com isso consigo fazer o resto.